# Highlight Masterpage menu to active state

Tags: javascript, menu, webforms, adminlte

I am using AdminLTE template. I have menu with child menus. I am redirecting different pages using image button. Now my menu collapses to original state.

If I navigate in menu alone it is working fine, but if I click an image button in any one of the menu item's web form, Menu is not active, it loses it active state.

[image: Second Image]

Highlighted in right top corner where I am Adding,Editing & Deleting pages are called. My requirement is that Hardware Menu should be active until I redirects to any other menu.

Javascript code I tried for Menu, It works for Menu items.

```
var url = window.location;
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function () {
    return this.href != url;
}).parent().removeClass('active');


$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');

// for treeview
$('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want in the box tools link a active state?

Comment: What I want is,if I click add/edit/delete imagebutton on top right corner my menu hardware should be active. like wise for other submenus page. Everypage has these three image buttons.

Comment: Please add a example of your box tools buttons

Comment: Can you help me please ?

Comment: If I understand right you want in the box tools link a active state? - Yes